# Finding duplicate and unique value in array and converting a string to array in object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to find the all the unique values in an array and if it has duplicate then the "name" field of the duplicates id's should be converted into an array.I tried to display the unique values but  I'm unable to get the duplicate and covert to array.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to add a new element to the array.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

//document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits;

function myFunction() {
var fruits = [{"name":"Banana","id":1}, 
{"name":"Grape","id":1}, 
{"name":"Apple","id":2},
{"name":"Mango","id":1},
{"name":"Banana","id":3}];

 let orgArray = [],output =[],l = fruits.length, i;
 for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
    if( orgArray[fruits[i].id]) continue;
    orgArray[fruits[i].id] = true;
    output.push(fruits[i]);
}
 console.log(output,'asdasdasdasdasd');





}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

In the above code, the final value of the array should be like

```
  resultArray = [{"name":["Banana","Grape","Mango"],"id":1}, 
{"name":"Apple","id":2},
{"name":"Banana","id":3}];
```

Comment: You can sort the array of Objects based on id, then while iterating through the array, if the next element's id is same as current ones, then store them in an array and continue till you find a different id, then repeat the same process. Or else you can find if the current ID already exists in your output array by iterating through it, then if it exists then add it to the array, create a new object otherwise.

Comment: @YouKnowWhoIAm, could you please post with an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a two stage process. It creates a map by key of the grouped fruits, and then iterates over that map and returns an array of objects; an object with an array for name property where there are more than one elements, or just the single value if there isn't.

```js
var fruits = [{"name":"Banana","id":1}, {"name":"Grape","id":1}, {"name":"Apple","id":2},{"name":"Mango","id":1}, {"name":"Banana","id":3}];

// Iterate over the fruits array assigning
// an object as the initial value
const temp = fruits.reduce((acc, c) => {

  // Destructure the id and name from the
  // current element in the iteration
  const { id, name } = c;

  // If the object key doesn't already exist give a new array value
  // otherwise (if it exists - it's an array) concat the name to it
  acc[id] = (acc[id] || []).concat(name);

  // Return the object for the next iteration
  return acc;
}, {});

const out = Object.entries(temp).map(([key, values]) => {
  if (values.length > 1) return { name: values, id: key };

  // If there is only one element in the values array return
  // that element instead of the whole array
  return { name: values[0], id: key };
});

console.log(out);
```

Further reading

- [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)
- [`Destructuring assignment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Answer (score 1):

First, you need make a set from ids to make them unique. Then you create array and map it. You should filter initial array in order to get the names for every id

```
 Array.from(new Set(fruits.map(item => item.id))).map(id => {
    const names = fruits.filter(item => item.id === id).map(item => item.name);

    return {
      id,
      name: names.length === 1 ? names[0] : names
    };
  })
```

Comment: You should perhaps go over and comment the steps you've taken to arrive at your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can either sort the array based on the `id` in the array of objects, or iterate through the array of objects, store them in a dictionary (i.e., an object)

Here is the code that could explain the above line,

```
var fruits = [
    {"name":"Banana","id":1}, 
    {"name":"Grape","id":1}, 
    {"name":"Apple","id":2},
    {"name":"Mango","id":1},
    {"name":"Banana","id":3}
];

var mapper = {};
var out = [];
for(let ob of fruits){ // Step 1
    if(mapper[ob.id] != undefined) mapper[ob.id].push(ob.name); // Line 1a
    else mapper[ob.id] = [ob.name]; // Line 1b
}
for(let key in mapper) out.push({id:key,name:mapper[key]}); // Step 2
```

**Step 1:** Here you iterate through the fruits array of objects, and while iterating if you find that if the element is new then you store it in a new array (line 1b), otherwise if the element's `id` already exists in the object then you can simply add an element to the array by using `push`

**Step 2:** In this step, you can directly push elements of the object `mapper` into the `out` array by creating an object with `key` as its `id` and the array present at `key i.e., mapper[key]` as the value

Answer (score 0):

```js
function uniqueFruitIds(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
    return accumulator.includes(currentValue.id) ? accumulator : accumulator.concat([currentValue.id])
  }, [])
}

function myFunction(arr) {
  return uniqueFruitIds(arr).map(id => {
    const namesArray = arr.filter(fruit => fruit.id === id).map(fruit => fruit.name)
    return {
      id,
      name: namesArray.length === 1 ? namesArray[0] : namesArray,
    }
  })
}

const fruits = [
  { name: 'Banana', id: 1 },
  { name: 'Grape', id: 1 },
  { name: 'Apple', id: 2 },
  { name: 'Mango', id: 1 },
  { name: 'Banana', id: 3 },
]

console.log(myFunction(fruits))
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of **reduce** method of Array prototype as below:

You can use lodash library if you do not want to do below with groupBy and other extensive utilities.

```js
var fruits = [
  {"name":"Banana","id":1}, 
  {"name":"Grape","id":1}, 
  {"name":"Apple","id":2},
  {"name":"Mango","id":1},
  {"name":"Banana","id":3}
];

var reducedArray = fruits.reduce(function(newArray, current){
     var foundItem = newArray.find(function(item) {
        return item.id === current.id;
     });
     if(foundItem) {
        foundItem.name.push(current.name);
     } else {
        newArray.push({ "name" : [current.name ], "id" :             current.id });
     }
   return newArray;
}, []);

console.log(reducedArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I hope it works for you:

```js
var fruits = [{"name":"Banana","id":1}, 
{"name":"Grape","id":1}, 
{"name":"Apple","id":2},
{"name":"Mango","id":1},
{"name":"Banana","id":3}];

let resultArray = [];

let arrayToReplace = ["Bannana", "Apple", "Mango"];

fruits.forEach(a=>{
    let index = resultArray.findIndex(x=>x.id==a.id);
    if(index > -1){
        resultArray[index]["name"] = arrayToReplace;
    }
    else{
        resultArray.push(a);
    }
});
console.log(resultArray);
```